# How can I build a specific architecture using xcodebuild?

Tags: macos, command-line, xcode4, xcodebuild

I have legacy code that relies on pointers being `32-bit` and want to use `xCodeBuild` to build that code from `command line`. This doesn't work for some reason. Here's the command I use:

```
xcodebuild -configuration Debug -arch i386 
  -workspace MyProject.xcworkspace -scheme MyLib
```

here's the output I get

```
[BEROR]No architectures to compile for 
  (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=x86_64, VALID_ARCHS=i386).
```

Clearly it's trying to build `x86_64` code and failing miserably since I only enabled `i386` from `VALID_ARCHS` in xCode project settings.

Is there a way to make it understand I don't want a `64-bit` library?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You have to set the `ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH` to `NO` if you want `xcodebuild` to use the `ARCHS` parameters. By passing these parameters, you can force the proper architecture.

```
xcodebuild ARCHS=i386 ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration Debug -workspace MyProject.xcworkspace -scheme MyLib
```

See [this reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html) for details.

Comment: according to the reference provided looks like using ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES and CURRENT_ARCH=i386 should work for what i want to do but CURRENT_ARCH (or NATIVE_ARCH which has same meaning) but apparently those two variables can't be overridden (and nothing seems to suggest it from documentation). Proposed approach did work (and actually it makes sense once you understand active arch is the build system's architecture instead of the one you selected in Xcode) but probably a better choice of word for that definition would have helped. Thanks!

Comment: You can use `xcodebuild VALID_ARCHS=i386 CURRENT_ARCH=i386 ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES ....`

Comment: Just adding  ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO did it for me

Comment: For 64 bit simulator / os:
ARCHS='x86_64' VALID_ARCHS='x86_64'

Comment: What does Geoptima to do with this here? The `ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO` answer is correct, your comment is useless

Comment: what if I want to use ARCHS_STANDARD?

Answer (score 3):

**Build Active Architecture Only(ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH)**

```
xcodebuild ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH...
//or
Build Settings -> Build Active Architecture Only -> ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH
```

`YES` - build binary with a single architecture for a connected device

`NO` - build binary for a specific `-arch`(`valid architectures` aka `VALID_ARCHS`) if it was specified or for all the architectures in other cases

The recommendation is to use `Yes` for Debug (to save on build time) and `No` for Release build.

[image]

Note: it is safe to run on simulator

To check the version use `lipo -info`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59215277/4770877)