# How to update just one library from the Cartfile with Carthage?

Tags: carthage

My Cartfile has many libraries. When I do `carthage update` it goes through all the libraries. That can take very long time.

Is there a way to update just a single library with carthage? Something like this? (this will not work)

```
carthage update "evgenyneu/moa"
```

Answer (score 167, accepted):

From [0.12 version](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/releases/tag/0.12) `build`, `checkout`, and `update` take an optional space separated list of dependencies

For a Cartfile like the following

```
github "Alamofire/Alamofire"
github "ReactiveX/RxSwift"
```

You could choose to update one dependency

```
carthage update Alamofire
```

or multiple dependencies

```
carthage update Alamofire RxSwift
```

If you need to add flags, add them last:

```
carthage update Alamofire --platform iOS
```

Comment: **carthage update Box --no-use-binaries --platform iOS**      // if you need to specify additional flags

Comment: @Alex Salom: Box being the name of the repo in the Cartfile? would be easier to understand if you used something more familiar like AlamoFire maybe? And what is the Result portion? Another repo name or?

Comment: @GitSyncApp, yeah you have to write the names of the dependencies separated by spaces. I edited my answer

Comment: @MartinRomañuk what exactly doesn't work? I've just tried the example above with `carthage bootstrap` and it only processed one dependency from the two defined in the Cartfile. Take a look at the screenshot from my terminal https://pasteboard.co/I9bARyq.png

Comment: @AlexSalom to be fair, you are using `bootstrap` while the answer says to use `update`. With `bootstrap` you are downloading whatever the `Carfile.resolved` says, it won't update.

Comment: `carthage update Box --platform ios --use-ssh --cache-builds --use-xcframeworks`

Answer (score 13):

Carthage supports updating single dependencies now.If you have something like this in your Cartfile:

```
github "bitstadium/HockeySDK-iOS"
```

Then you can update only this one dependency by running

```
carthage update HockeySDK-iOS
```

Answer (score 9):

Right now the answer is no... If your run `carthage help update` you'll see

```
Update and rebuild the project's dependencies

[--configuration Release]
    the Xcode configuration to build (ignored if --no-build option is present)

[--platform all]
    the platform to build for (ignored if --no-build option is present)

[--verbose]
    print xcodebuild output inline (ignored if --no-build option is present)

[--no-build]
    skip the building of dependencies after updating

[--use-ssh]
    use SSH for downloading GitHub repositories

[--use-submodules]
    add dependencies as Git submodules

[--no-use-binaries]
    check out dependency repositories even when prebuilt frameworks exist (ignored if --no-build option is present)

[--color auto]
    whether to apply color and terminal formatting (one of ‘auto’, ‘always’, or ‘never’)

[/path/to/your/app]
    the directory containing the Carthage project
```

As you can see there is no mention to an option to specify only one dependency to update.

You should [open an issue on the project repo](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues) asking to support that.

Answer (score 9):

If the framework isn't stored in GitHub, or you are using the `git` identifier, and your `cartfile` looks like this:

```
git "ssh://git@bitbucket.org/teamname/repo-name.git" ~> 1.0
```

then you can update only that one running the following command

```
carthage update repo-name
```

Answer (score 7):

I tried all of the answers, and for me only **removing** or **commenting** temporarily the repositories and after running

`carthage update --platform ios`

after I restore the Catfile to previous state

Answer (score 5):

I ended up writing my own script that builds a single dependency for me and merges it with my existing dependencies.
You can find it at https://github.com/ruipfcosta/carthage-workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

**Carthage --no-use-binaries and specific schema**

[[Carthage flow]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61397563/4770877)

```
carthage [update|bootstrap|checkout|build] [dependency1] [dependency2] [--no-use-binaries] [--platform <name>]

//--no-use-binaries - does not use prebuild binary and use source code
//--platform - specify a platform
```

The longest phase is a `carthage build`(xcodebuild) step because:

1. `carthage build` generates `fat binary` which is built using `lipo`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59215277/4770877)
2. Carthage builds all `shared frameworks schemes` of a project. If you know which exactly schema which you need you can:

   - [UI] Open built project from `Carthage/Checkouts` folder -> Manage Schemes... -> check specific schemes
   - [Manually] Leave specific schemes at `xcschemes` folder `.../Carthage/Checkouts/<dependency>/<project>.xcodeproj/xcshareddata/xcschemes/<schema>.xcscheme`

[[Carthage --no-use-binaries]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66954027/4770877)

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5

```
//MARK:- Step 1
carthage update KeychainAccess --platform iOS

carthage update SDKNAME(like i mention KeychainAccess upper) --platform iOS
```

if you face an Error like this

```
//MARK:- If this error occur
error: unable to find utility "xcodebuild", not a developer tool or in PATH
```

Then use Part 1 in Terminal Again

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

and again

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `carthage update repo-name` doesn't work on `Carthage 0.36.0`.
I solved this problem by manually updating `Carthage.resolved`. For example, add to a `Cartfile` a new dependency:

```
github "konkab/AlamofireNetworkActivityLogger" ~> 3.0.0
```

Add to a `Cartfile.resolved` a new dependency manually:

```
github "konkab/AlamofireNetworkActivityLogger" "3.0.0"
```

Then do `carthage bootstrap` to only update one dependency:

```
carthage bootstrap
```

It will use `Carthage.resolved` and just add one dependency.