# Quickest way to add Carthage in Xcode Project

Tags: ios, xcode, dependencies, carthage

What is quickest way to add dependencies in Xcode project using Carthage.

How to add or edit dependencies later.

Answer (score 11):

Install Carthage

[Download Carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/releases)

Open terminal

> Terminal: cd ~/Path/To/Folder Containing Project

Create Carthage file as:

> Terminal: touch Cartfile

Open Cartfile file from project folder and add required dependency

Example Cartfile file

> github "Alamofire/Alamofire" == 4.5
>
> github "Alamofire/AlamofireImage"

After Editing Cartfile file save it.

Run following command from terminal

> Terminal: carthage update --platform iOS

xCode > Build phases

- Plus button on top left > New Run Script Phases
- Run Script > Shell script window > add following:

> /usr/local/bin/carthage copy-frameworks

- Run Script > Input file window > add following:

> $(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/DependencyName.framework

- Link Binary With Libraries > Plus button > Add Other > Navigate to
  Project Folder > Carthage > Build > iOS >
     Framework to add

[image]

Done

Comment: Question: shouldn't there be some dependency on the framework in "Target Dependencies"? Incase you modify the Cartfile, then have carthage recompile it? Just to insure the new framework is linked in on a "run"?

Comment: easiest guide I could find. Better than even the official docs. +1

Comment: In my test this doesn't work for building for the simulator. Perhaps at this point the instructions on the Carthage page work better: https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage#quick-start

Answer (score 2):

**Using Carthage flow**

[[iOS Dependency manager]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59257708/4770877)

TL;DR:

```
Download dependency -> build fat binary -> it should  be imported -> slice for release
```

Long version:

1. Installing Carthage

   ```
   //Homebrew
   brew install carthage
   ```
2. Create `Cartfile` file at the project(`.xcodeproj`)/workspace(`.xcworkspace`) directory
3. Modify `Cartfile`. Add necessary **dependency** == **repo**

   ```
   github "<owner>/<repo>" == <version>
   ```
4. Run `carthage update` under `Cartfile` location. High level logic:

   ```
   `carthage update [dependency]` {
       - reads `Cartfile`, resolves dependency graph and generates `Cartfile.resolved` to store a list of versions that will be actually built

       //--no-use-binaries - this flag force a Carthage to not use a `Prebuilt framework`
       //--no-build - this flag skip a building step - `carthage build`

       `carthage bootstrap [dependency]` {
           - reads `Cartfile.resolved`
           `carthage checkout [dependency]` {
               `carthage fetch <path>` {
                   - fetch dependency from `Cartfile.resolved` into `~/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/` folder
               }
               - checkout/move a dependency from `~/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/` to generated `Carthage/Checkouts` folder
           }
           `carthage build [dependency]` {                
               - builds all `shared frameworks schemes` from `Carthage/Checkouts` into generated `Carthage/Build` folder

               //--no-skip-current - (+current consumer)this flag also builds all `shared frameworks schemes` of a consumer workspace/project(in addition to `Carthage/Checkouts` folder)
           }
       }
   }
   ```
5. Drag and drop builded frameworks to `General -> Frameworks and Libraries`

   ```
   //framework location
   <cartfile_path>/Carthage/Build/
   ```
6. Run the next script. This step is important because carthage build a `fat` binary(arm64... + x86_64) using `lipo`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59215277/4770877). Apple reject application which uses it. That is why you should add this extra step to cut architecture for simulator(x86_64)

   ```
   Build Phases -> + -> New Run Script phase -> 

       // /usr/local/bin/carthage - path to Carthage, copy-frameworks - command which sets a necessary architecture and copies framework to an application bundle
       Shell -> /usr/local/bin/carthage copy-frameworks

       //path to a generated Carthage/Build
       Input files -> + -> $(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/<platform>/<name>.framework
   ```

*Any `carthage` command should be called from `Cartfile` folder

If you run into some error

```
This usually indicates that project itself failed to compile. Please check the xcodebuild log for more details: /var/folders/2q/jhrcxkmx49g21lydqfrf26ph0000gn/T/carthage-xcodebuild.AySUH3.log

//you can use open command to review the log
open /var/folders/2q/jhrcxkmx49g21lydqfrf26ph0000gn/T/carthage-xcodebuild.AySUH3.log
```

Crear Carthage cache

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit
```

**Get stuck on `update`**

```
carthage update --platform ios --verbose --new-resolver

//e.g.
//The dependency graph contained a cycle
```

Use XCFramework[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67181295/4770877) `--use-xcframeworks`

```
//error
Building universal frameworks with common architectures is not possible. The device and simulator slices for "<schema_name>" both build for: arm64
Rebuild with --use-xcframeworks to create an xcframework bundle instead.

//solution
carthage update --platform ios --verbose --new-resolver --use-xcframeworks
```

[[Carthage --no-use-binaries]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66954027/4770877)

[[Fast Carthage build]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61408166/4770877)

[[Local Carthage]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61397924/4770877)

Answer (score 0):

- **Install** carthage on your mac: `brew install carthage`
- **Create a `Cartfile`** in the project root directory, e.g. `vim Cartfile` and paste:

  ```
  github "AFNetworking/AFNetworking" ~> 4.0
  ```
- **Build** the frameworks: Run `carthage update --platform iOS`

  - Warning: dependending on the library you are using, you'll need to follow their instructions on what `carthage update` command to run specifically. You may need to run e.g. `carthage update --use-xcframeworks --platform iOS --no-use-binaries` instead. Check their readme.
- **Add it to Xcode:** In finder, navigate to `$project_dir/Carthage/Build`. You will find a `FrameworkName.framework` or `FrameworkName.xcframework`. **Drag the `.framework`/ `.xcframework`** into your Xcode Project (in the project navigator).