# Module compiled with Swift 5.3.2 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.6 compiler

Tags: ios, swift

After updating to Xcode 13 and trying to run my app on an iOS 15.4 simulator, I get the following error (note, this is not a repeat question).

This error **doesn't** occur when I run my app on an iOS 14.X simulator in Xcode 12, so why is it happening now?

```
Module compiled with Swift 5.3.2 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.6 compiler
```

What is causing this error and what steps need to be taken to fix it?

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sE1Us.png)

[Error image #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hkvZ.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Module compiled with Swift 5.0.1 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.1 compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58130048/module-compiled-with-swift-5-0-1-cannot-be-imported-by-the-swift-5-1-compiler)

Comment: I tried everything on that page but nothing worked unfortunately

Comment: So you removed all of the Carthage artifacts and reinstalled them with Xcode 13 tooling as the command line tools?

Answer (score 0):

Clear derive data to remove compiled module of old version. Then run again