# Is Mapbox Navigation compatible with Swift 5.0

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox, carthage

Can anyone confirm that [Mapbox Navigation](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/navigation/overview/) works with Swift 5.0 or for that matter they are still a going concern?  I have now tried building the frameworks in Carthage using Xcode 11.3 and a fresh install of Xcode 11.6 on a brand new Mac running the latest OS and in both cases when trying to import framework:

```
Module compiled with Swift 4.2.1 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.2.4 compiler:
```

According to some answers to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55352985/module-compiled-with-swift-4-2-1-cannot-be-imported-by-the-swift-5-0-compiler), this happens when Developer has not yet released their app for Swift 5, although the [Mapbox changelog](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-ios/blob/v0.40.0/CHANGELOG.md) claims they have

Have tried contacting Mapbox through every conceivable channel and radio silence. Hopefully they are still in business and supporting the software but I'm not sure.

Comment: Downvote but no comment or response? To Anonymous, if you know anything, please share it. If you don't know anything, please remove downvote

Answer (score 0):

> Module compiled with Swift 4.2.1 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.1.3
> compiler:
> /Users/M/Desktop/War/idaru/MapboxCoreNavigation.framework/Modules/MapboxCoreNavigation.swiftmodule/arm64.swiftmodule

This error appears because you still have a built copy of MapboxCoreNavigation on your system and Xcode is linking against it instead of building from scratch. It’s always necessary to do a clean build when upgrading Xcode.

If you encounter this error message within Xcode when building your application target, please clean your build products using Product ‣ Clean Build Folder and build again. If you're seeing this error on the command line when running carthage update, you can try cleaning your Carthage caches using the following command:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/carthage/ ~/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/binaries/
```

Comment: I have tried those steps as well as cleaning the project but it hasn't worked. Do you think the old copies of the frameworks could reside in the Git repo?  Alternatively, do I need to clean out the modules cache? 

~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache directory.

 Where could the old versions be hiding?