# How to fix this error " Could not find module 'CzsBleSdk' for architecture 'x86_64'; found: arm64, arm "

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, swift4.2, ios-bluetooth

I'm working with bluetooth in an old project which was written in swift3 and i'm working on converting it in swift4 and I had this error
"Could not find module 'CzsBleSdk' for architecture 'x86_64'; found: arm64, arm"

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to create a simulator build but you don't have an x86 version of that framework; you can't use Bluetooth in the simulator anyway.  Test using a real device

Comment: yes but i only need to run this app, it says always build failed.

Comment: Are you trying to run it on a device or the simulator?

Comment: the simulator, just to verify the app if it can run or not, and no, i can't run it nor build it.

Comment: You can't build this for the simulator as you don't have an x86 version of the framework. If you can't get an x86 build of the framework then you will need to limit your testing to a real device. Realistically you need to use a real device anyway since, as I said, you can't use BLE on the simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are now using 64 bit architecture in your Swift 4 project. You'll need the latest CzsBleSdk SDK which supports 64-bit architecture. You can integrate that manually or using Pod. I personally recommend Pod.

Comment: the problem is i've been searching for this SDK but i didn't find it. and the project is working with this SDK.

Comment: This must be a private framework. You need to contact the developer who created this. Else there is no option.

Comment: @Nitish I have a framework xcode project include source code, how to I build to a private framework?

Answer (score 1):

I seems that your framework was built and published the binary for the **real device** - armv7, armv7s, arm64 and you try to run a build for a **simulator** - x86_64.

Usually when a publisher wants to share a library he should create a `Universal` aka `Fat` binary using `lipo`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57790700/4770877) command.

- If it is open source project you can import the project and Xcode will solve this issue
- If it is closed source you can try to find it on Cocoapods or ask the publisher to upgrade the framework