# How to correctly build armv7 static library using xcodebuild

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcodebuild, armv7

I am trying to build a static library to target armv7.

I am using the following command in a bash script:

```
$XCODEBUILD -project 'MyLibrary.xcodeproj' -target "MyLibrary" -configuration 'Release' -sdk 'iphoneos7.0' clean build ARCHS='armv7 armv7s' IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='5.0' TARGET_BUILD_DIR='./build-arm' BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR='./build-arm'
```

I cannot link to the resulting lib. I get linker error:

> file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): ~/MyProject/MyProject/libMyLibrary.a

Is something wrong with the way I am building the binary?

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update**
The target that I am trying to build (the application linking to the lib) has the following settings:

[image]

Comment: Go to project setting and set Build Active Architectures Only option to No. This may solve problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check Build Settings (for the target you are trying to build!) - make sure that both `Architectures` and `Valid Architectures` are set to the same values.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Architectures was set to Standard(Including 64)armv7, armv7s, arm64. I tried setting this and Valid Architectures to only include armv7 and armv7s but the problem persists.

Comment: You want them the same, not different.  Did you try also setting "Valid Architectures" to include arm64?  Alternately, did you try setting both to not include arm64?

Comment: I updated with a screen shot showing my settings. This is what you were suggesting right?

Comment: I was editing the build settings for the application which is linking to my static lib. I made the same edits to the static lib's settings and it worked. Thanks a lot for the the help!

Comment: Aha!  That is why I included "for the target you are trying to build", because it's easy to forget you are editing a different target than what you are building!

Answer (score 1):

Try setting ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCHS=NO in your command.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151549/how-can-i-build-a-specific-architecture-using-xcodebuild) as well

Comment: This didn't seem to make a difference.